# could not find class, No class definition found

Tags: java, android

I'm getting `Could not find class` and `No class definition found` error in Android

Those classes is inside the jar files. I've added the jar files in a separate folder, but it is not recognized at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The JAR isn't in the CLASSPATH.  That error means that the class loader can't find it.  Don't believe your eyes; believe the class loader.

Comment: how to set that jar in to the classpath. I have just added that jar in separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

@ddffymo is right.

Have you configure the Build Path? If not here is a way to configure it along with library.

1. create lib or libs folder inside your project structure and then add that library file(JAR) inside this folder.
2. **Right click** on this JAR file, select **Build Path -> Add to Build Path**.